# Importing database in PostgreSQL in rails application

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am facing one problem to import database into PostgreSQL.

I go through by 
select database >>go to Tools>> restore >> Restore Database >>choose my database  xyz.back >> rolename -postgres >> after that Restore button is inactive.

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no  there is no error msgs..when select file then Restore button is inactive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This may help**
Your database backup file contains error or format is not supported for import.

Comment: what is the actual extention of file backup/dump

Comment: Do you already have database created and column don't match? if not export in sql format the import

Comment: Thank you  pradeep my database backup file contains error or format is not supported for import.

solving issue by chaging the database file and extention from .dump to .backup